Cannot enable sound with bb even with pasuspender
For this problem, I had trouble with getting bb to work with pipewire. Executing the command pasuspender -- env PULSE_SERVER= bb returns Failure to suspend: No such entity.
How do I enable bb with sound when using pipewire?

Add PULSE_SERVER= to /etc/environment and reboot. The problem is solved as the variable PULSE_SERVER is not even set in the environment variables.
